# Trigger function displays ''Global events are unsupported and deprecated''

Tags: jquery, jquery-migrate

I am new to jQuery and I'm trying to update a project to use the latest version of jQuery (1.10.2) along with using the jQuery migration script. I'm using Chrome for testing and the migration script is reporting that the following function line $.event.trigger(event) is a global event that is unsupported and deprecated. Could someone please explain what this means? I looked at the jQuery website documentation and the format of the function seems to be correct.

```
function trigger(event, callback) {
        if (callback) {
            callback.call(element);
        }
        $.event.trigger(event);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it means... doing $.event.trigger(event) is deprecated. don't do it. Instead, trigger the event on the element.

Comment: To make sure I understand, so it should be written like this: $('#element').trigger(event); ?

Comment: Yes, that would be the correct way to do it now that global events are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by using $(element).trigger(event); 
Thanks goes to Kevin B